# SQL OR & AND Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently having problem with a SQL query, It is as follows

```
UPDATE table
SET result = 6
WHERE date between DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL - 4 DAY)
AND curdate() 
AND TEAM1 = 6 OR TEAM2 = 6
```

Searching for this date range in a select statement works fine, its when i try to SEE IT TEAM1 OR TEAM2 = 6

The Database i am using is MySql through PhpMyAdmin.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: The database you are using is MySQL (actually it's not a "database" it's a Relational DataBase Management System), not PHPMyAdmin. PHPMyAdmin lets you see the databases and tables in MySQL. Google it when you have time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table
SET result = 6
WHERE 
    date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL - 4 DAY) AND curdate() 
  AND 
    (TEAM1 = 6 OR TEAM2 = 6)
```